# IDL: how to create PDF file?

Tags: pdf, plot, idl

I'm struggling to save my data in pdf file with IDL.

Here is an example. The problem is that official manual has only instructions for "PLOT()" function. And I can't find anything for "oplot" function.

```
plot, x, y, psym=5, yrange=yr, xrange=xr, xtitle='R', $
       ytitle='Orbit'
oplot, x1, y1, psym=5, color=7*16-1
```

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the only way to create a PDF directly in IDL is through function graphics, i.e., the `PLOT()` function. To do it from direct graphics, like you have above, create a PostScript file and convert it to a PDF using some other utility like *Preview.app* or *ImageMagick*.

Comment: You can also use "ps2pdf [filename]" on the command line. https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Ps2pdf.htm